# Graph / matrix from dataframe by conditiom

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this

```
df = data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), y=c('a','b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 
                'a', 'b', 'd'))
```

I want to get a matrix / graph as below

```
  a b c d
a 0 4 1 1
b 4 0 1 1
c 1 1 0 0
d 1 1 0 0
```

where 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' are levels of df$y and cell is filling by df$id. For example the cell 'a'-'b' = 4 because for id 1 'a' and 'b' intersect twice, for id 2 'a' and 'b' intersect one time, for id 4 'a' and 'b' intersect one time, total 4 times. Etc.... 
Thanx for any idea...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option is to get the `crossprod` on `table` and then multiply with a `diag`

```
out <- crossprod(table(df)) * !diag(length(unique(df$y)))
out
# y
#y   a b c d
#  a 0 4 1 1
#  b 4 0 1 1
#  c 1 1 0 0
#  d 1 1 0 0
```

and remove the 'y' attributes by setting it to `NULL`

```
names(dimnames(out)) <- NULL
```